# Trouble creating login form in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-csrf

I'm a little new to Django, and I'm trying to create a login form for the users of my site. I'm using Django's user app. i've created a simple form with username and password fields as follows:

```
<form id='login-form' action="login" method="post">
<div class='login-field'><input type='text' name='username' placeholder=' Username'></div>
<div class='password-field'><input type='password' name='password' placeholder=' Password'spellcheck='false'></div> <br />
<input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' spellcheck='false'>
</form>
```

the problem i get when pressing the submit button is:

`CSRF verification failed. Request aborted`

I've looked through all the solutions to similar questions on this site and others and still haven't been able to solve the problem, any suggestions?

Comment: Just wanted to re-iterate @JamesO's comment below here, in case it gets overlooked by anyone needing this answer. You must use RequestContext to have `{% csrf_token %}` return anything: `return render_to_response('login.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `{% csrf_token %}` somewhere inside your `<form>` tag in the template.

See the [Django docs on Cross-site request forgery](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) for more information.

Comment: That should be all you need. Make sure you've restarted the server and refreshed the page before trying it again.

Comment: You need to use RequestContext when rendering the view.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Cross Site Request Forgery protection](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#module-django.middleware.csrf) in the docs.

Basically you need `{% csrf_token %}` after the form tag.

Comment: do you have django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware in you settings.py? Is RequestContext being returned with the template? e.g.return render_to_response('login.html',                       context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: added it... still same problem